# iptables have both "accept all anywhere anywhere" and "drop all anywhere anywhere" rules

Tags: iptables

I' confused. This is my iptables config:

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 3 TTL-Match name: sshprobe side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: SET name: sshprobe side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8181
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8008
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm confused that there is both the following lines in Chain INPUT:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I cannot actually determine that port 25 or 587 (where postfix is running) is open from outside, or MySQL port 3306.

**The question is: why I'm seeing that ACCEPT rule?**

This is how my iptables are set with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ATTENTION: flush/delete all existing rules
iptables -F

################################################################
# set the default policy for each of the pre-defined chains
################################################################
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# allow establishment of connections initialised by my outgoing packets
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# accept anything on localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

################################################################
#individual ports tcp
################################################################
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8181 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8008 -j ACCEPT
#uncomment next line to enable AdminGUI on port 4848:
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4848 -j ACCEPT

################################################################
#slow down the amount of ssh connections by the same ip address:
#wait 60 seconds if 3 times failed to connect
################################################################
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --name sshprobe --set -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --name sshprobe --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 --rttl -j DROP

#drop everything else
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
################################################################
#Redirection Rules
################################################################
#1. redirection rules (allowing forwarding from localhost)
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8181

#2. redirection http
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

#3. redirection https
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8181
################################################################
#save the rules somewhere and make sure
#our rules get loaded if the ubuntu server is restarted
################################################################
iptables-save > /etc/my-iptables.rules
iptables-restore < /etc/my-iptables.rules
#List Rules to see what we have now
iptables -L
```

EDIT:

As per a comment by @Michael Hampton this is the output of `iptables -v -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 3 TTL-Match name: sshprobe side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: SET name: sshprobe side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
1580M 1033G ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  25M 1524M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
 824K   33M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
 186K   11M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
2053K  115M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
  40M 2302M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8181
5272K  226M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
 183K   11M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8008
 858K  106M DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1845M packets, 1964G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: You also need to include `-v` to see the entire rule. Otherwise important parts are omitted. This is a ridiculous oversight in the `iptables` command...

Answer (score 16):

@Michael Hampton suggested that I should run

iptables -v -L

And there I discovered those two rules are actually:

```
  25M 1524M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
 858K  106M DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Which actually means that the first rule accept anything on localhost and it is defined by the rule from my config:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Thank you very much, Michael Hampton!